# Explanation of git push origin behavior

Tags: git

I am new to git. I set up a repository on a server and working on a local clone. I kept committing to my local repository and after a point I see the following message -

```
"Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 5 commits."
```

So I did a `git push master` and then I still see the same message above when I do a `git status`.

After reading up a bit I realized that `git push master` will only  push the changes to the remote branch. So I did `git push origin` which resulted in `Everything up-to-date`. After that point `git status` does not tell me that the branch is ahead of the origin/master.

I do not understand why `git push origin` resulted in `Everything up-to-date` when clearly they are not from the previous command. Can some one explain what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ git push -h
usage: git push [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]
```

To put it simply, the first argument of `git push` is normally the name of a remote. For example `origin`. The second argument is usually a local branch, for example `master`. Here are a couple of examples and what they do:

```
git push
# --> push all local branches to the remote branches they are tracking

git push origin
# --> push all local branches tracking branches on origin to origin

git push origin master
# --> push the local master branch to origin/master
```

Your first attempt, `git push master` should not work or do something strange: it will only work if you have a remote called "master", which is not normal, as "master" is typically used for the main branch name. Your second attempt, `git push origin` worked, because it pushed your local tracking branches, including `master` to `origin`.